# Lowering privileges of executed script

Tags: unix, redhat, setuid

I'm writing an auditd plugin, which is executed as root user by auditd, and as per the  man recommendation I'm looking to lower it's privileges.

I assumed just setting the scripts setuid would be sufficient but that appears to not be the case. Any suggestions how I can get the script to run as the owner rather than as root?

```
# chmod u+s listerner.sh
# ls -lt
total 20
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root          10 Oct 26 13:59 listener.bash.log
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 mike mike  60 Oct 26 13:58 listerner.sh
```

When i run the file as root, it generates a log file owned by root, and when it runs: whoami - it also outputs root.

The test script is very simple and doesn't do anything other than what I described above:

```
# cat listerner.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

whoami

echo "Test file" > listener.bash.log
```

I tried the same with a Python script initially as well, and got the same behaviour.

So not sure if I've misunderstood how to use setuid, or perhaps its been disabled on this server (RHEL 8).

Comment: Setuid bits are not honored by the kernel when executing any sort of script. The actual binary that is running is the script interpreter: `/bin/bash` for example. Unless that binary is setuid root, no privilege will be available. In most cases, setting something like `/bin/bash` up as a setuid-root binary will ruin the security of your system.

Comment: `su - user -c THESCRIPT` maybe?